What's a convenient way to look up a `DispatchError` in RPC
A DispatchError will refer to a pallet and a member of the pallet's Error enum by index:
DispatchError: {"module":{"index":123,"error":456}}

How can I wrap these and convert them within my node before issuing out the response to the rpc request.

This is not supported on the node side out of the box.
You could write something that uses the metadata to decode the error and transform it. Best is actually to have the tool interacting the chain parse the metadata to read these errors.
Another possible solution could be that you write your own runtime api for decoding the error:
decl_runtime_api! {
    trait DecodeError {
        fn decode_error(dispatch_error: DispatchError) -> String;
    }
}

In your runtime you then implement this runtime api:
// For `format!`
extern crate alloc;

implement_runtime_apis! {
    impl DecodeError for Runtime {
         fn decode_error(dispatch_error: DispatchError) -> String {
              RuntimeError::from_dispatch_error(dispatch_error.clone())
                .map(|e| alloc::format!("{e:?}"))
                .unwrap_or_else(|| alloc::format!("{dispatch_error:?}")) 
         }
    }
}

Then you could call this runtime api in your RPC in the case of an error.

Any ideas on how I Would even find the way that dispatchError codes and decodes the errors?. I thought just converting the error message into a string and then wrapping it around the Error pallet would be enough but its not.

Extended my answer.
